# Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Here's my problem .
I have just my Visual Basic 6.0 Enterprise Edition
When I run the Setup or any .exe something pop out saying that the file is not a valid win32 application.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Vb 6 is very old, I am not surprised it is incompatibile with modern versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running the application from the CD.

- Right-click **setup.exe**. From the Properties window
- Select the **Compatability** tab
- Check **Run this program in compatability mode for**
- Select **Windows XP** from the drop-down menu
- Click **OK**

This will run the application in an older version of Windows. If this fails, you may want to consider installing Windows XP or older on a machine to run this aged software.